# How to Remove Characters Conditionally in Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data-frame as below:

```
index     status
 1       IPAMR-104.129.194.150-104.129.194.161;Clayment-STARR-65.115.39.42
 2       Noti8nalMI-64.73.114.92-127.0.0.1
 3       HSO_fm-dev-apps255-128.11.45.165
```

I'd like to remove all unwanted characters and remain with and output as shown bellow. I have tried this 
`rs = df.replace(r'[^\d.;-]+','',regex=True)` but no luck

```
index     status
 1       104.129.194.150;104.129.194.161;65.115.39.42
 2       64.73.114.92;127.0.0.1
 3       128.11.45.165
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do `findall`

```
df.status=df.status.str.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}').str.join(',')
Out[122]: 
0    104.129.194.150,104.129.194.161,65.115.39.42
1                          64.73.114.92,127.0.0.1
2                                   128.11.45.165
Name: status, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.extractall` and then `groupby`:

```
df['status'] = (df.status.str.extractall('(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')
                  [0].groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)
               )
```

Output:

```
   index                                        status
0      1  104.129.194.150;104.129.194.161;65.115.39.42
1      2                        64.73.114.92;127.0.0.1
2      3                                 128.11.45.165
```